# What is best practices play video on tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I can play video on tableViewcell but I don't know best practices. 
I create a avplayer view controller on tableview cell. Play video when call (tableView:cellForRowAt:indexPath:) but it's underperformance.

```
class NewsfeedVideoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, Reusable, NibLoadable {
var playerVC: AVPlayerViewController?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!
    player = AVPlayer()
    playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerVC!.player = player
    contentView.addSubview(playerVC!.view)
    playerVC!.view.frame = contentView.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you should to do:

1. Keep one instance of player in parent View Controller. (init each time player in cell not so good idea)
2. Stop playing when cell move out from visible space
3. Use prepare for reuse in any case for new reuse process
4. When usr select some new cell. Stop previous video and inject video player to selected cell in prepared frame

All depends on your requirements. IMHO `AVPlayer` in each cell not good idea which related to large memory use and start/pause/stop processing.